# Segment fault (core dumped) with c

Tags: c, coredump

There is no problem when compiling with `gcc` on `linux`, but when I run this code, It always reports

> Segment error (core dumped)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main ()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch,str[10240],arr[10800][3];
    int i,j,k;
    if((fp=fopen("structure_backup.dat","r"))==NULL)
        {
        printf("\nCannot open file!!!");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
        }

    ch = ' ';
    i = 0,j=0,k=0;
    while(ch != EOF)
        {
            ch = fgetc(fp);
            while(ch !='\n')
                {
                    while(ch != '\t')
                    {
                        str[k]=ch;
                        k++;
                    }
                    arr[i][j]=str;
                    k=0;
                    j++;
                }
            arr[i][j]=str;
            k=0;
            j=0;
            i++;
        }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: First obvious error: ch is a char, and fgetc() returns an int.

Comment: You should not declare big arrays like these on the stack. Use dynamic memory for those.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main ()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch,str[10240],arr[10800][3];
    int i,j,k;
    if((fp=fopen("structure_backup.dat","r"))==NULL)
        {
        printf("\nCannot open file!!!");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
        }

    ch = ' ';
    i = 0,j=0,k=0;
    while(ch != EOF)
        {
            ch = fgetc(fp);
            while(ch !='\n')
                {
                    while(ch != '\t') // <=== HERE is where you go off the rails, never escape this whileloop
                    {
                        str[k]=ch;//<==== NOW YOU STORE ch in str[k], never escaping the while loop
                        k++;//<=== k goes to MAX_SIZE here, eventually causing the write above to be out of bounds.  str[9999999999] is an invalid index for example.
                    }
                    arr[i][j]=str;
                    k=0;
                    j++;
                }
            arr[i][j]=str;
            k=0;
            j=0;
            i++;
        }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I have copied your OP source and put comments where the segfault happens.   You either need to re-get ch in the nested while loop, or make the nested while loop an if statement.  Either way theres your segfault :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(ch != '\t')
{
str[k]=ch;
k++;
}
```

If ch is not '\t', then this is infinite loop, because the value of ch does not change and the array str will overflow.

For example, if ch is 'a', then the vale of str[k] is 'a', k increased, and do this loop again while 'a' != '\t', then str[k]='a', k increased, ..., till array str overflow.